# Can we specify the size of DATANODE in hdfs file system

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

While formatting `DATANODE` with following command:

```
hdfs dfs datanode -format
```

**Is it possible to specify the size of `HDFS`**? I understand horizontal scalability will be impacted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDFS is as large as the datanodes attached to it... So by adding more hardware you are specifying the size.

It's not like a disk that you can partition (at least, not in the general sense of allocating specific sizes of disk for specific tasks).

Comment: so you mean so say it will be managed by `namenode` if let say one `datanode` harddisk is full it will copy data in other `datanode`? and keep address of that data in metadata of `namenode`?

Comment: By default, 3 HDFS blocks are copied across all datanodes and Metadata is managed by the namenode for where those blocks are. Therefore, if all datanode disks are the same size, if one datanode is filling up, that would likely indicate your entire cluster is close to full. In that case, I believe HDFS will shutdown and not allow more writes by saying its out of space